# Unhandled exception, however I have a Try catch

Tags: vb.net

My application calls a webservice through some classes. It will purposely throw an ApplicationException if the webservice returns false.

The call to the webservice is triggered from a buttonclick and calls a method to complete the request. This method includes the Try/Catch block, However when debugging in Visual Studio 2017, the ApplicationException is unhandled.

Object graph:

> - click event calls SendManifest() (in form)
> - SendManifest creates an object and calls its sendManifest()
> - *this call is wrapped in try catch*
> - another object is instanciated and sendManifest() called
> - this function receives a result from the webservice call.
> - If that result is false, it throws an applicationexception with the result message.

Example:

```
Private Sub SendManifest()
    Try
        Dim fi As New FreightInterface()
        fi.SendManifest(manifest)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim msg As String = "An exception occurred sending the manifest file: " & ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

```
Public Class FreightInterface
    Public Function SendManifest(Byval manifest)
        Dim FreightIntegration
        FreightIntegration = New SubFreightIntegration()
        Return FreightIntegration.sendManifest(manifest)
    End Function
End Class
```

```
Public Class SubFreightIntegration
    Public Function sendManifest(ByVal manifest)
        Dim freight As Object = Nothing
        Select Case manifest.carrier
            Case "POST"
                freight = New PostFreight(manifest)
        End Select

        Dim r As Result = freight.sendManifest(manifest)
        If r.result Then 
           Return True
        Else
            Throw New ApplicationException(r.message)
        End If
End Class
```

I considered that the webservice call in the PostFreight() class could cause issues because it is async and requires waits. However the exception message is correctly formed, just not caught.

So therefore I suspect that the intermediate class FreightInterface is unable to pass on the Exception correctly.  My alternative might be to simply pass up the result object and have FreightInterface throw if it needs to.

Comment: First things first, why do you have functions declared without a return type?  You should set `Option Strict On` and then fix all the issues that it flags, including those ones.

Comment: What about when not using the debugger?  It might just be your settings.

Comment: Some of the classes do have a return type specified, but i had edited them out of the post for clarity. I ran the app outside of VS and it was an unhandled Obj Ref error.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce what you're describing using the code you've supplied. The code reaches the `Catch` block and the `msg` variable is assigned a value. What happens when you step through the code line by line, starting at the `SendManifest()` call in your `Click` event handler?

Comment: @InteXX When I throw the ApplicationException, that's unhandled. The FreightInterface is unable to 'return' the result from the subfreightintegration.

Comment: `When I throw the ApplicationException, that's unhandled` But it *is* handled. By the `Try/Catch` construct in your code. That's what I meant when I said that execution reaches the `Catch` block. The code you supplied must differ from the code you were running.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I choose two approaches:

As suggested, The classes now specifies return types, and;
I pushed the ApplicationException into the FreightInterface class. There's further utility in being able to process results from that class as well, so I think it's a good solution for now.